# Django: Sum Total value over Foreign Key Data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.11 and Python3.5
I have created a table. This is a screenshot.
[image]

When I got a table from my query database, it is showing 10+2+3...  but I want to get total sum value for every customer within ***Due Taka update*** column in table like this 10+2+4+2 = 18

this is my model.py file

```
class CustomerInfo(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField('Customer Name', max_length=100)
    customer_mobile_no = models.CharField(
        'Mobile No', null=True, blank=True, max_length=12)
    customer_price=models.IntegerField('Customer Price',default=1)
    customer_product_warrenty = models.CharField('Product Warrenty',null=True, blank=True,max_length=10)
    customer_sell_date = models.DateTimeField('date-published', auto_now_add=True)
    customer_product_id=models.CharField('Product ID',max_length=300,null=True, blank=True)
    customer_product_name=models.TextField('Product Name')
    customer_product_quantity=models.IntegerField('Quantity',default=1)

    customer_uid = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    customer_info=models.TextField('Customer Details Informations', blank=True, null=True)

    customer_conditions=models.CharField('Conditions',blank=True, null=True, max_length=300)

    customer_due_taka_info=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    customer_discount_taka=models.IntegerField(default=0)


    customer_first_time_payment=models.IntegerField('First Time Payment',default=0)
    customer_first_due_info = models.CharField('First Due Info',default='No due info', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    customer_product_mrp=models.IntegerField('Products MRP', default=0)

    customers_refrence=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    customer_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    customer_type=models.CharField('Customer Type', default='MobilePhone', max_length=50)






    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer_name

    def remainBalance(self):
        if self.customer_price > self.customer_due_taka_info:
            remain=self.customer_price - self.customer_due_taka_info
            return remain


    def totalRetalsPerSingle(self):
        return self.customer_product_quantity * self.customer_product_mrp





    #def product_warrenty(self):
        #expire_date_oneyr =self.customer_sell_date+ datetime.timedelta(days=365)
        #return 'This product expire on this date ' + str(expire_date_oneyr)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("গ্রাহকের তথ্য")
        verbose_name_plural = ("গ্রাহকের তথ্যসমূহ")




#intregated with Customerinfo Model (Using foreignKey)
class DueTaka(models.Model):

    customer_due = models.IntegerField('Due Taka', default=0)
    customer_due_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    customer_due_info=models.CharField('Due Info', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    customerinfo = models.ForeignKey(CustomerInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    due_customer_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.customer_due

    def sum_total(self):
        return self.customer_due
```

this is my views.py file

```
due_update_info = CustomerInfo.objects.filter(duetaka__customer_due_date__range=(starts_date, tomorrow)).order_by('-customer_updated')
```

I want to get total price **customer_due** fields within ***DueTaka*** model for per single customer. if a customer name is 'asad'. He has some multple due taka and he paid multiple times like this 10+20+20 Now I want to get total value like 50

If I update my customer's profile, same customers name come again with in loop my table. But I don't want this.
[image]

and this is my html template file

```
<h1>Due Paid Book</h1>
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <p style="font-size:16px;">Due Paid Tody</p>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>

                <th>Invoice ID</th>

                <th>Mobile</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Product MRP</th>
                <th>Customer Paid (TK)</th>
                <th>Due Amount</th>
                <th>Total Price</th>

                <th>Warrenty</th>
                <th>Purchase Date</th>
                <th>Due Taka update</th>
                <th>Update Date</th>
                <th>QN</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        {% for x in due_update_info %}
        <tbody>
            <tr>
.......code in here.......
                <td> 
                    {% for y in x.duetaka_set.all %}
                    {{y.customer_due | intcomma}}+
                    {% endfor %}
                    {{x.duetaka_set }}
                    <!--i want to toatal value in here, now nothing showing-->
                    {{total_price}}


                </td>



            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </tbody>



        {% endfor %}
        <td colspan="10"></td>
        <td> Total Du Paid <br> <i>{{starts_date}} to {{end_date}}</i> </td>
        <td> <b>{{dupaid_today|intcomma}} TK</b> </td>

    </table>
```

Now How can I implement in views file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe change the filter query like this this:

```
CustomerInfo.objects.filter(duetaka__customer_due_date__range=(starts_date, tomorrow)).annotate(due_taka_total=Sum('duetaka__customer_due')).order_by('-customer_updated')
```

which will give you additional field 'due_taka_total', which can be used in template, like:

```
{{ y.due_taka_total }}
```

assuming y is an object of CustomerInfo

**OR** 
You could write a custom template tag and find out the total using it:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_total_taka(customer_info_object):
    return sum([each.customer_due for each in customer_info_object.duetaka_set.all()])
```

and use it in template like this:

```
{% get_total_taka y %}
```

assuming y is an object of Customerinfo

For writing the custom template tag refer: [Writing Custom Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters)

Comment: CustomerInfo.objects.filter(duetaka__customer_due_date__range=(starts_date, tomorrow)).annotate(due_taka_total=Sum('customerinfo__customer_due')).order_by('-customer_updated') I think It is not correct. Because Sum('customerinfo__customer_due') this line check. There are "customer_due" no fields within CustomerInfo Table.

Comment: Sorry about that, just missed that. updated the answer.

Comment: If I update my customer's profile, same customers name come again with in loop my table. But I don't want this.

Comment: Which one did you use? The annotate or template tag?

Comment: I got the total price on my table. But the same name comes again when I update.

Comment: How did you get the total_price?

Comment: template tag file.

Comment: Use distinct() in your filter query. ie, CustomerInfo.objects.filter(duetaka__customer_due_date__range=(starts_date, tomorrow)).order_by('-customer_updated').distinct()

Comment: Working Fine. But distinct stop duplicate?

Comment: Yes it will prevent duplicates.

Comment: Okay. I understood. This eliminates duplicate rows from the query results.